# Unable to Remove a Users Permissions from a doc.lib item in a event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-level-permissions, role-assignment

As per my requirement i need to remove a particular user from his permissions from  document library item .There is a field called Assigned_To in my docu.lib and I DONT want HIM to access the docu.item based on a status column. 
ie, when the value of status column is set to **deallocated**, i need to remove this user from accessing this item.

How this can be achieved using C#?
  i tried the below code:

```
    for(int i = newFile.Item.RoleAssignments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
             {
     newFile.Item.RoleAssignments.RemoveById(newFile.Item.
     RoleAssignments[i].Member.ID);
                }
```

but this code somehow didn't work.

is there any otehr way of achieving this? I cant use removeallassociations of this partiular item.Thats the reason I am trying to achieve for a single user.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code:

```
for(int i = newFile.Item.RoleAssignments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
     newFile.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove("Pass your SPUser Object");
   }
```

Hope it works for you.